# Is this a 100% correct sentence?

Tags: idioms

I am trying to create professional poster for my company's annual function.

Quote No.1 ->

**Colleagues share food, wingman share fate.**

Quote No.2 ->

**Colleagues share food, wingmen share fate.**

Which of the two is correct ?

Comment: Some would argue since the two halves are full sentences on their own, a semicolon would be better than the comma: Colleagues share food; wingmen share fate.

Comment: . . .  and some would argue in favour of the comma splice .

Comment: I agree with mike65535 but at the same time,. what you're asking is clearly some combination of proof-reading and literary criticism so it has no place here.

Comment: Do you think that colleagues are people who share food with each other?

Answer (score 1):

The second one because the first half of the sentence refers to a group of people, "(plu) colleagues", thus the second half should also be in its plural form. I feel your purpose is to separate the ordinary from the extraordinary. Thus when you showcase this slogan publicly you can't keep first half plural and second half singular- "wingman". And secondly we are talking about sharing so it's "wingmen" again..

Answer (score 0):

The second one.

For the first one to be correct, it would need a determiner (*a*/*the*) and the verb would need to be in the 3rd person singular (*shares*)

Comment: Agreed. Although "share fate" sounds a but odd. Should it be "your fate" or "their fate" (I'm not quite sure what a wingman is in this context) and then "their food" to keep the parallel structure?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assume _wingmen_ is used in an aviation context (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingman) or something? That would make sense with _fate_. As it's a slogan, the _their_ would be omitted, otherwise is does indeed sound odd.